# Is there a method to invalidate a whole list of controls on a ribbon?

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office

On a Word/Outlook (any MS-X ribbon)-
If an action (say a login) affects more than 2 or three other elements on the ribbon is there a built-in method that accepts a list to invalidate all of them at once?

Currently, this is what I'm doing -

```
List<String> li = new List<String>() { "CtrlA", "CtrlB", "CtrlC", "CtrlD"};   
// I may have a couple more

foreach(string element in li)
{
   ribbon.InvalidateControl(element);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up making a separate method that I call everytime with the list as the parameter. This isn't any different from what I'd done in my question apart from the fact that now the readability has improved :-/ But it works fine for me in terms of invalidating just the elements I need invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

Call IRibbonUI.Invalidate to invalidate the whole ribbon.